# Calculating time spans with datetime2

Tags: datetime2

With datetime2, is there a way to calculate an end time from a start time if I have the duration in minutes? Something like

```
\newcommand*\timespan{90}
\newcommand*\starttime{13:45:00}
\DTMtime{\starttime+\timespan}
```

(analoguous to `\DTMdate` where you can add days)

I don't see anything in the docs, but I have the impression it might be possible via `\DTMfetchhour` and `\DTMfetchminute`.

(The background here is changing start time with a fixed duration, and I want to automatically output the whole slot including the end time)

Comment: Calculating clock times is trickier due to the need of using modulo computation -- adding days is not that difficult. Apparently neither `datetime2` nor `datetime2-calc` provide such features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a preliminary version, using `expl3` features and calculating the total number of seconds, then splitting and calculating the new time.

It does not indicate that the time span is more than 24 hours, so using a timespan of multiples of 1440 (minutes) will result in the same time as the start time.

Wrapping hour values after midnight is done.

`datetime2` does not provide macros in order to calculate time spans or end times in sense of hour:minute:seconds -- there are some computation macros concerning dates.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\newcommand*\timespan{90}
\newcommand*\starttime{13:45:00}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_set:Nn {NV}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVn,NVV}

\NewDocumentCommand{\endtime}{+m+m}{%
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \seq_set_split:NVV \l_tmpa_seq {\c_colon_str} \l_tmpa_tl
  \exp_args:NNx \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1} * 3600 + \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2} * 60 + \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {3}  }
  \exp_args:NNx \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpb_fp {#2 * 60}
  \fp_add:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {#2 * 60} 
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl 
  % Compute hours
  \exp_args:NNx \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_div_truncate:nn {\fp_use:N \l_tmpa_fp}{3600}}
  \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int } > {23} {% After midnight?
    \exp_args:NNx \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {\int_mod:nn {\l_tmpa_int } {24}}
  }{%
    \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_int \l_tmpa_int
  }
  \tl_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_tl {\l_tmpb_int\c_colon_str}

  % Remaining seconds, split them into minutes and seconds 
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\fp_use:N \l_tmpa_fp}

  \exp_args:NNx \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {\int_mod:nn {\l_tmpa_int}{3600}}
  \exp_args:NNx \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {\int_div_truncate:nn {\l_tmpb_int}{60}}
  \tl_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_tl {\l_tmpb_int\c_colon_str}
  % Finally splitting: Seconds
  \exp_args:NNx \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_mod:nn {\l_tmpa_int}{60}}
  \tl_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_tl {\l_tmpa_int}
  % Display output:
  \exp_args:NV \DTMtime{\l_tmpa_tl}
  \group_end:
}



\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
We started at \expandafter\DTMtime\expandafter{\starttime} 

The event lasts \timespan\ minutes

It ends at \endtime{\starttime}{\timespan}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly for my needs (the 24h limitation is not an issue). If you don't mind, I'll integrate this code into my [jslectureplanner](https://ctan.org/pkg/jslectureplanner) package (of course with appropriate credits)

Comment: @JSpitzm: Permission granted -- please come back occasionally, I will improve my 'hacky' solution from time to time. I will look forward to your package